# make: no rule to make target

Tags: linux, makefile

i have written a simple linux module & its make file

this is my module

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void) {
  printk("<1> Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void) {
  printk("<1> Bye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

this is my make file

```
    obj-m :=Hello.o


KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

when i execute make -f MakeFile
it gives following o/p

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17 SUBDIRS=/home/linux/Desktop modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/linux/Desktop/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/linux/Desktop/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/linux/Desktop] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

can any one tell me how to get rid of these errors.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why it's needed to set `SUBDIR` to `$PWD`? Are you having the file `/home/linux/Desktop/Makefile`? In my experience there's no need to set `SUBDIR`. You may try remove `SUBDIR` in `all:` and re-make it.

Comment: thanks for replay after removing subdir this error apper        make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Oh sorry for my careless reply. I suppose what you shall do is to recover the `SUBDIR` and rename your `MakeFile` into `Makefile` and try again, since it's missing the file `Makefile` and `*nix` is case sensitive.

Comment: This is the error i get now  /home/linux/Hello.c:1:32: fatal error: include/linux/init.h: No such file or directory
any additional libraries required to compile module

Comment: @PushkarDhande I guess your problem now solved

Answer (score 2):

Make the below change in your Makefile

First check which kernel is running by typing uname -a

Then go to cd /usr/src/

then check your linux source-code name

for e.g

uname -a Linux vinay-VirtualBox 3.2.0-50-generic-pae #76-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 19:24:55 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

here its source-code name is linux-headers-3.2.0-50-generic-pae
same thing in your case 
e.g

linux-headers-3.2.0-23  linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
so use `linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae` instead of 
linux-headers-3.2.0-23 i.e replace same in your makefile

i.e KDIR=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic-pae

or in order to avoid above problem use
`KDIR == /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)
KDIR == /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: Nope dude, `$PWD` is an environment variable in the shell, whose content is exactly the same as the result of `pwd`.

Comment: also make sure your Makefile name is correct as starrify said

Comment: also refer same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223653/linux-makefile-example/19224677#19224677

Comment: i dont got any directory named as  linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae i made some changes as you said now i get following error include/linux/mmzone.h:18:30: fatal error: generated/bounds.h: No such file or directory
thanks for help

Comment: its an example i have given . see your directory cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic-pae

Comment: i got only one folder in usr/src what are the files mmzone.h & bounds.h as in error. Sorry for such foolish things  i am new to linux & module writing

Comment: Just follow below links http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/12/writing-your-first-linux-driver/  and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223653/linux-makefile-example/19224677#19224677

Comment: include/linux/mmzone.h:18:30: fatal error: generated/bounds.h: No such file or directory
how to remove this error getting it after following steps in your link

Answer (score 0):

```
obj-m += xyz.o

KDIR:=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-46-generic

all:

       make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:

       make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Are you sure `/usr/src/` contains linux-headers-3.5.0-46-generic files?
if this is not the case, download:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-46

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-46-generic
```